# async function returns Promise { <pending> }?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have the following async function:

```
async function readFile () {
  let content = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./file.txt', function (err, content) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      resolve(content)
    })
  })

  console.log(content)
}

readFile()
```

This runs just fine. It outputs the file buffer to the console as expected. But now, if I try to instead return the value:

```
async function readFile () {
  let content = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./file.txt', function (err, content) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      resolve(content)
    })
  })

  return content
}

console.log(readFile())
```

I now get:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Why is this? Why can you use a value inside that function but when you return it out of the function it's now a Promise?

How do you actually make use of this in a normal workflow? For example, lets say I wanted to check if a file exists, then read in the file, then update some database with the content, the synchronous pseudo code would look something like this:

```
if (fileExists(path)) {
  buffer = readFile(path)
  updateDatabase(buffer)
}
```

That workflow consists of 3 individual async operations. How would you do something like this with `async/await`? Is the key that you have to have your entire script wrapped in an `async` function?

```
async function doSomething () {
  if (fileExists(path)) {
    buffer = readFile(path)
    updateDatabase(buffer)
  }
}
```

(Keep in mind that is just pseudo-code but hopefully its gets my point across).

Comment: `async/await` is just sugar for promises, so, any function tagged `async` will always return a promise

Comment: `async` functions do *not* make your code synchronous (why would they be called async then...) *"Is the key that you have to have your entire script wrapped in an async function?"* That works. Or use promises as usual: `if (fileExists(path)) { readFile(path).then(updateDataBase);}`.

Comment: your `async function doSomething()` can use `buffer = await readFile(path)`

Comment: What is the point of async/await then? I could just return a Promise like usual if I have to use `.then()` after the function.

Comment: @JakeWilson pretty code.

Comment: @JakeWilson: It lets you write async code in a synchronous *style*. But at the very top level you are still dealing with a promise.

Answer (score 8):

All `async` functions return a promise as was mentioned in the comments.  You could therefore re-write your `readFile` function like this:

```
function readFile() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./file.txt', function (err, content) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      resolve(content)
    })
  })
}
```

You would then consume the return value of `readFile` via `await`:

```
console.log(await readFile()) // will log your actual file contents.
```

The usual workflow with this paradigm is to break your async operations into separate functions that each return a promise, and then run them all inside a broader `async` function, much like you suggest, but with `await`s and some error handling like so:

```
async function doSomething () {
  try {  
    const fileCheck = await fileExists(path)

    if (fileCheck) {
      const buffer = await readFile(path)
      await updateDatabase(buffer)
      // Whatever else you want to do
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // handle any rejected Promises here.
  }
}
```

Comment: If the function returns the promise anyway, you could drop the `async`

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. I'm curious if anyone is expected to you `async/await` in a node module for example, does the entire module need to be wrapped in one big `async` wrapper function or something? I guess when I look at all examples of `async/await` in action I don't see a lot of real world examples yet. Just a lot of people are using `someAsyncFunction` instead of a legitimate library function in their examples.

Comment: You wouldn't "wrap the library."  You would just `await` the result of the library function.  [Here](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool#plays-nice-with-asyncawait) is an example with node-postgres.  You need to confirm the library uses promises though, else you would have to wrap any callback based methods in a function that returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
const serchContentXmlFile = async (path, content) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      resolve(data.indexOf(content))
    })
  })
}

await serchContentXmlFile("category.xml",xmlUrl);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation on your code.